# Show that a basis for $P_3(\mathbb R)$ need not contain a polynomial of each degree $0,1,2,3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that a basis for $P_3(\mathbb R)$ need not contain a polynomial of each degree $0,1,2,3$.

I would have thought that a basis for $P_3(\mathbb R)$ would need a polynomial of each degree.
I am confused by this question and how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, does a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ need to be of the form $\{(0,0,\ast),(0,\ast,\ast),(\ast,\ast,\ast)\}$? (Your $P_3(\Bbb R)$ I'm guessing is 4D, but still.) Try your hand at *creating* a basis with all three polynomials having degree two or three. Literally just pick a polynomial, pick another, then think about the third.

Comment: Oh I see! It seems that I misunderstood the question! Ty

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the idea on a smaller space, consider $P_1(\mathbb{R})$. The basis will consist of two linear expressions, $p_1(x) = a_1 x + b_1$ and $p_2(x) = a_2 x + b_2$. We *could* choose $p_1(x) = x$ and $p_2(x) = 1$, giving us a degree 0 and degree 1 polynomial, but we could *also* choose, for example, $p_1(x) = x$ and $p_2(x) = x + 1$. It's pretty easy to show that these are linearly independent, but they also have the same degree.